MySQL - Join Table, Use COUNT and GROUP BY
I have question about MySQL "join table". Here I want to combine 3 tables. However, I need to count one column and group by it. I've no idea about the order of the codes. I failed to make it work. Tried "LEFT JOIN" as well when I reviewed some similar problems. Anyway it doesn't work.
SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name," ",e.last_name) AS "employee_name",COUNT(s.employee),s.date, i.price, i.category 
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN employees e ON s.employee = e.id
LEFT JOIN stock_items i ON i.id = s.item
GROUP BY s.employee
ORDER BY COUNT(s.employee) DESC LIMIT 1;

Error Message
MySQL said: Documentation
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '5126 db.e.first_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
I updated as below bt it still doesn't work./(ㄒoㄒ)/~~
SELECT  s.date, s.item, i.item, i.price, i.category, e.first_name, e.last_name, s.employee, COUNT(s.employee) FROM
stock_items i 
LEFT JOIN sales s
ON i.id = s.item
LEFT JOIN employees e
ON e.id = s.employee
Group BY e.id
ORDER BY COUNT(s.employee) DESC LIMIT 1;

This is my school assignment, and all the columns included are requested by the tutor.


Use GROUP BY e.id so it's a primary key.

The error message claims that s.employee used in grouping expression is not primary key column.  So you'd either add all another columns into the grouping expression or wrap them with aggregate function or remove them from the output list.

But i.price, i.category in the select list makes no sense. You're aggregating all the items, which price and category do you expect it to select?

The same with s.date -- you're aggregating all sales, so it makes no sense to select the date.

FYI, this will count the number of items the employee has sold, not the number of sales.

I'd like to count the top sales by employee. ------------------Error message this time-------------------------#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '5126 db.s.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
